# $compile unusual Behaviour

Tags: javascript, angularjs, conditional-statements

**Angular version:1.3**

I am trying to compile the html and generate the interpolated html. the `ng-if` code is getting commented out

**html**

```
<div ng-if="true">true</div>
```

I am using the above html as htmlTemplateDom

**Controller**

```
var htmlCompiledDom = $compile(htmlTemplateDom)($scope);
var div = angular.element("div#emailContent").append(htmlCompiledDom); 
console.log(div.html());
```

**Console**

```
<!-- ng-if:true -->
```

So the problem is `ng-if` is getting commented out.
Someone help !!!!

Answer (score 0):

I don't see any problems on `$compile`.

This example works just as expected, check if you're doing something different.

HTML:

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="controller">
    <div id="compile">
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
angular.module('app', [])
.controller('controller', function ($scope, $compile) {
    var template = '<div ng-if="true">true</div>';
    var content = $compile(template)($scope);
    angular.element('div#compile').append(content);
 });
```

If you want to execute it, take a look at this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t25d8jup/5/).